# alternatives to google adsense for ajax reloads

Tags: google-adsense, ajax

What alternatives to google adsense are availalbe that support the reloading of ads through and AJAX application?

I can't locate one.

Answer (score 3):

Google DPF has [released a new tag](http://www.google.com/support/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?answer=1649768) that supports ajax:

Flexibility:

The Google Publisher Tag supports all formats and devices, simplifying ad delivery to your web, mobile, and video content. The tag also supports:

- HTTPS Environments: Deliver ads into secure HTTPS environments.
- E-mail Ad Serving: Non-JavaScript tags available for use in email or other environments that don't support JavaScript rendering.
- Passbacks: Tag can be used in a third-party ad server.
- Asynchronous ad refresh: Refresh ads in environments that don't require page reloads.
  Single-Request Mode: Fetch and deliver all creatives simultaneously.
- Interstitial (out-of-page) creatives
- Guaranteed roadblocks